# Prepared statement result in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, prepared-statement

Converted my normal SQL queries to prepared statements a while back, but now I want to implement a function and I'm not sure how. Below is my current code:

```
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();

$query = "pretty long query...";

$stmt->prepare($query);

  $stmt->bind_param('ssii', $dienstenpage, $huidigegemeente, $startpoint, $limit);

  $stmt->execute();


  $stmt->bind_result($prepid, $prephoofdrubriek, $prepplaats, $prepbedrijfsnaam, $prepgemeente, $prepbedrijfsomschrijving, $prepbedrijfsslogan, $prepstraatnaam, $prephuisnummer, $preppostcode, $preptelefoonnummer, $prepfax, $prepemail, $prepwebsite, $prepbedrijfslogo, $prepdubb);

  $stmt->store_result();

  $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;



   while($stmt->fetch()) {

Here appears a nice div with all the data for every result (row)

}
```

All works fine, no hick-ups there. However, for some of the page I want to shuffle the first 20 rows (only the first 20!) of the result. Thanks to the help of others I learned the best way to do that is to put the result in a query and do this:

```
$first20 = array_splice($allResults,0,20);
shuffle($first20);
array_splice($allResults,0,0,$first20);
```

However, I'm not sure how to put the results in array? I should be able to do that in the while loop ($stmt->fetch), but not sure how? Once the results are in an array I can slice it with the code above, put in back in the array and display the results in the new order. How do I insert the rows in an array?

THE ANSWER WAS (COMPLETED CODE):

```
 $array = array();

    while($stmt->fetch()) { 
    $array[] = array('prepid'=>$prepid, 'prephoofdrubriek'=>$prephoofdrubriek, 'prepplaats'=>$prepplaats, 'prepbedrijfsnaam'=>$prepbedrijfsnaam);
    }

    $first20 = array_splice($array,0,20);
    shuffle($first20);
    array_splice($array,0,0,$first20);

    $number = count($array);

    $cnt = $number; // if you wanted to get them all you could set it to $cnt = array_count($array);
        for ($i=0; $i<=$cnt; $i++) {
        echo $array[$i]['prepid'];
        echo "<Br />";
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i would do is put it all into an array like you said and then echo it out.

```
$array = array();

while($stmt->fetch()) { 
    $array[] = array('prepid'=>$prepid, 'prephoofdrubriek'=>$prephoofdrubriek, 'prepplaats'=>$prepplaats, 'prepbedrijfsnaam'=>$prepbedrijfsnaam);
}
```

I have only put a few in the array to demonstrate how to do it.

Then to get the data out I would use a for loop.

```
   $cnt = 20; // if you wanted to get them all you could set it to $cnt = array_count($array);
   foreach ($i = 0; $i <= $cnt; $i++) { 
        echo $array[$i]['prepid'];
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I endend up using your method!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like the following

```
$arr_val=array();

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $arr_val[] = $stmt->fetch() //or your result row;
}

$sliced_arr = array_slice($arr_val, 0, 20);
array_splice($arr_val, 0, 20);
shuffle($sliced_arr);
$arr_new_val = array_merge($sliced_arr,$arr_val);
print_r($arr_new_val);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up using James' method though. I'm sure yours works fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Save the `$stmt->fetch()` into a variable and add a [parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

For multiple rows:

```
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
       $result = array_push($result, $row);
    }
```

Now you've extracted your data and you can `array_splice` it

```
$first20 = array_splice($result ,0,20);
shuffle($first20);
array_splice($result,0,0,$first20);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up using James' method though. I'm sure yours works fine as well, but I ran into a bit of a problem with the FETCH_ASSOC, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `fetchAll()`?

```
$arr = array_slice($stmt->fetchAll(), 0, 20);
shuffle($arr);
foreach ($arr as $a)
{
    echo $a['prepaid'];
}
```

If that takes up to much memory (as `fetchAll()` returns all rows) you can use `fetch()` but limit to 20 (no need to slice).

```
$i = 0;
$arr = array();

while (($row = $stmt->fetch()) && $i++ < 20)
{
    $arr[] = $row;
}

shuffle($arr);

foreach ($arr as $a)
{
    echo $a['prepaid'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up using James' method though. I'm sure yours works fine as well, but I wasn't able to get the fetchAll() function going, perhaps it's not supported on my server.

Comment: @user2704687 I think you should atleast take inspiration from my second code-snippet. Since that's limiting the size in the first part, instead of fetch, lets say 1500 row's of data in the first step, and then just cut off 1480 in the next step.. See?

Comment: hmmm I see your point. However, I still want to show the other 1480 rows, I just dont want to shuffle them. You would shuffle the first 20 results with the above method and display the rest as normal, but cutting off the first 20?